# Alamofire object mapper with core data

Tags: core-data, alamofire, objectmapper

I am writing an app where I have a dashboard which shows the list of users.So I have created an entity by the name 'User'. For mapping, I am using Alamofire object mapper. 
**SCENARIO**
Before making a call to the API, I am checking if network is available. If no, I fetch the entity from core data and show the saved results. If yes, I make a call to the ApI and get the objects from the API and save it to my context.
**PROBLEM**
Now when I get the objects from the API, I save the response in NSManagedObjectContext and it gets appended to the already present NSManagedObjects in my 'User' entity.What I want is that if the User is already present in the entity , I don't want to save that User object in my entity again.So in the first call, I have ,say, 20 objects in the DB, after the second call, the count increases to 40 and so on.I don't want that.How do I achieve this?

Comment: @TomHarrington I couldn't seem to find the exact answer.That's why I posted it here.Can you please provide me at the link.

Comment: @TomHarrington And though I have resolved this issue, I just want to know if that's the best way.

Comment: how did you solve the issue? I also face the same problem. Can you help me on the same? @Reckoner

Comment: @DeepakrajMurugesan Yes let me answer that.Please up vote if you are able to resolve this issue using my answer.

Comment: lets say your User model has 20 elements on first time api call. And how will you make sure that on second time api call response the elements are same means not update, different means update or delete like that ??? @Reckoner. And is this the best way to solve the above mentioned issue. Thanks a lot for the quick reponse. I will upvote it no issues in that

Comment: When you get the response, just save your context. So now, you have, say, 20 elements in your context. After receiving second response for the same API, if you get 20 elements again with same IDs, but different values, they will be overwritten. Just try it and then ask if you have some issues.

Comment: how to add unique constraints to the relationship attribute if i have any !! @Reckoner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 'unique constraints' to resolve this issue. Its basically like primary key only. So when you add the 'id' in your entity as a unique constraint, the duplicate managed objects won't be stored in the context. Here is the link that you can follow:
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-Implement-Unique-Constraints-in-Core-Data